# How to define MongoDB schema validations at (db) collection level?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using MongoDB with mongoose and Nodejs. After defining the schema (ref - [See](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/schema-validation/)) it works when I try enter something from the code.
Like - if try following code

```
// User Model
User.create({name: 'rahu', status: 'randomStr'});
```

And the type of `status` is actually enum - `['active', 'pending', 'deactivated', 'blocked']`

It works perfectly and `throws the error for the allowed values for status`.

But when I insert/update values from Compass(or robomongo or any other code where schema is not defined) it saves the wrong value.

> So my question is - is there any way to create these
>   constraints/validatioons at db level like in PostgreSQL?

Thanks

Comment: Post your schema

Comment: Did you define the schema-validations in mongoose or did you manually set the validations on the DB-schema using db.createCollection()?

Answer (score 0):

You define the scheme in `mongoose` or directly in `mongodb`? It is not the same.
The problem remains if you define the scheme directly in mongodb? https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/schema-validation/

JSON Schema validation starting in version 3.6.

Comment: Mongoose uses the methods provided by mongodb so yeah. I just double checked their code, and they use the same db.createCollection() method to define the schema and validators. thanks though